# mongodb command list after open connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I use the method in this doc?
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionInfos/#db.getCollectionInfos

I had

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

mongoose.connect(`mongodb://example.com/db`)
const db = mongoose.connection

exports.default = (dropAllCollections = () => {
  db.on('open', function() {

    console.log(db.getCollectionInfos)


  })
})()
```

but got `TypeError: db.getCollectionInfos is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongod = mongoose.connection;

mongod.once('open', function (){
    console.log(mongod.db.getCollectionInfos)
})
```

try this,
Actually, we have to write .once('open') for getting the db instance in mongoose.

Comment: I'm able to connect but got this error`TypeError: mongod.db.getCollectionInfos is not a function`

Comment: which is your mongod version? because the documentation says that the method you are trying get is new in 3.0

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am getting the same error.